# Terminal and log canonical singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, birational-geometry, divisors, resolution-of-singularities

Let $D$ be a divisor with at most terminal singularities in a smooth projective variety $X$. Is the pair $(X,D)$ log canonical?

Comment: This is simply because inversion of adjunction. This pair is PLT.